# About plotting several curves with different vertical scales (more than 2)

Tags: plotting

I look for the plotting of several curves with different vertical scales. The context is to draw in one plot the 4 curves (jerk, acceleration, velocity and displacement) of a finite jerk motion profile.

This topic has already discussed in the following post :
[Two vertical axes in the same plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/229961/two-vertical-axes-in-the-same-plot)
[Plot with multiple Y-axes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/164846/plot-with-multiple-y-axes)

The second one seems to be good but it is difficult to understand and consequently to modify to adapt to my case.

Consequently, i made this small code :

```
ScaledPlot[fcts_, coef_, dom_, options___] :=
 Plot[Evaluate[coef*fcts], dom, 
  Evaluate[PlotLegends -> 
    MapThread[
     Row[{##}] &, {coef, {"\[Times]\[ThinSpace]j[t]", 
       "\[Times]\[ThinSpace]a[t]", "\[Times]\[ThinSpace]v[t]", 
       "\[Times]\[ThinSpace]q[t]"}}]], options]

ScaledPlot[{j[t], a[t], v[t], q[t]}, {1/40000, 1/200, 1/10, 1}, {t, 0,
  1}, Filling -> Axis]
```

It is almost good but i have some discontinuities for the acceleration :
[image]

and i think these discontinuities come from display issues. Indeed, i have no issue when i plot the acceleration curve alone (see below):

[image]

**1) Have you some ideas to correct the discontinuities that i obtain in the display when i try to plot the 4 curves in the same plot with my method ?**

**2) Is there somebody interested to make the code present in this post ([Plot with multiple Y-axes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/164846/plot-with-multiple-y-axes)) more accessible so that it can be used easily ? i would like to use this code but i'm not able to do it for the moment**

The code which enables me to obtain these motion profile curves was given in this post :

[Finite Jerk Motion Profile](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/275943/finite-jerk-motion-profile/276134#276134)

Comment: Providing your functions `j[t], a[t], v[t], q[t]` might increase the chance to get helpful answers!

Comment: the code is quite big. The code is given here (in a former post) as i said at the end of the post : https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/275943/finite-jerk-motion-profile/276134#276134

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`MultiaxisArrangement`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MultiaxisArrangement.html) option of [`ListLinePlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListLinePlot.html):

```
ListLinePlot[
 Cases[
  Plot[{j[t], a[t], v[t], q[t]}, {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, Exclusions -> None],
  Line@pts_ :> pts,
  All
  ],
 MultiaxisArrangement -> All
 ]
```

[image]

Unfortunately, the option is not yet directly supported for `Plot`, so I extract the lines from the `Plot` command and replot using `ListLinePlot`. Also the option is still quite buggy, e.g. adding `Filling->Axis` leads to the same fill color for all curves:

[image]

Finally, note the added `Exclusions->None` in the plot command, this is to work around an issue in Mathematica 13.1.

Comment: @

interesting, and how can i do if i want than the max of acceleration be above the max of velocity so as to have better visibility

Comment: @Bendesarts Unfortunately I don't think that is supported yet

Comment: Consequently the best will be to simplify the code which is accessible here : https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/164846/plot-with-multiple-y-axes to make it accessible

Answer (score 0):

With the following option in the plot function : PlotPoints -> 1000
it works !